# How to synchronize (i.e.Seed and Download) torrent without internet?

Tags: networking, sync, download, bittorrent

How to synchronize partially downloaded torrent files without internet?
I am downloading a big torrent file size 80 GB approx. if I use Desktop computer for downloading that file its a problem of unnecessary power consumption but Desktop computer have more storage capacity. But more power consumption.
So I think if I use mobile to download that torrent files its solve that power problem. But mobile have very less storage.
To solve above both problem I got a solution, that is download torrent files step by step with mobile and seed that torrent files from mobile to PC. 
To achieve above goal I want a method which surely work offline torrent synchronize?
How to synchronize torrent from mobile client to PC or vice versa?

**other Info.**

Torrent down-loader on PC- utorrent.
torrent down-loader on Mobile-Flud.

In below pictures Local IP from mobile and PC both display but they unable to shake-hand and seeding and downloading pieces in user control but sometimes randomly that download and upload torrent pieces. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: You just need to copy the completely downloaded data...?

Comment: @DanielB But this is not useful for step by step downloading and very big data. pieces downloading and synchronizing is useful for that.

Comment: So basically you want to perform partial downloads to your mobile, then move the download fragments piece by piece to another machine and reassemble them? I don't see how that could work as the once you move the pieces from your mobile, the Torrent client will not know you already downloaded those chunks and will try to download them again. Plus torrents are in random order, if there are 1000 chunks you don't get them as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc, you might get 1, 300, 7, 999, 40, 1000, etc.

Comment: @acejavelin yes I want that. But I can choose folder by folder downloading on flud and therefor I can overcome that random downloading problem with torrent. also in torrent sequentially downloading option also work. But random pieces also useful.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. When you want to partially download a torrent, at some point, the files you selected to download are complete. You need to move those files. That’s it. If the download is just one large file, your plan cannot work.

Comment: @DanielB Actually yesterday accidentally my both torrent client shake-hand torrent pieces and utorrent client downloading from flud in **DH L** flag without internet. And that same thing I want as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to share torrents over a local network is when both clients support [Local Service Discovery](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0014.html)